# The Data Collection Agent (DCA) had an unhandled exception

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a brand new on prem service fabric install with out any applications running on it, just the base services.  Its using Windows authentication for both cluster and remote communication.  2 out of the 3 nodes immediately go into a failed state and show:

> Error event: SourceId='FabricDCA', Property='DataCollectionAgent.'.

The Data Collection Agent (DCA) had an unhandled exception and will be stopped. Diagnostics information will be left uncollected if this continues to happen.

This seems to be intermidtant because one node just came back up.  Then another will fail, even the one that was working in the first place.  Has anyone run into this before. This other post looks similar but there wasn't an answer to it:

[The data collection agent dca had an unhandled exception and will be stopped](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/9f578186-bfa1-4817-a8e2-6a37ef413d9c/the-data-collection-agent-dca-had-an-unhandled-exception-and-will-be-stopped?forum=AzureServiceFabric)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you run eventvwr and look in 'Applications and Services Logs'->'Microsoft-Service Fabric'->Admin for any error events with Task Category = FabricDCA?  That should have more details on the exact error you are running into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found that Network Service didn't have access to the location of the Service Fabric Logging location.  We had added it but Group Policy kept removing it.  After updating the group policy this error went away and the cluster was stabilized.

To Alter's point we used Microsoft Message Analyzer to view the logs and then added the **ETW.ETWProviderMessage.EventRecord.Header.Descriptor.Level** Column to find the errors.  Errors are level 2 and warnings are level 3.  You can then filter or group by that column.  After you do this you need to use the level 4 informational messages around your error often to debug.

Best of luck, I'm riding up that learning curve...
Greg